# Signing OS X app on Windows (without codesign)

Tags: xcode, macos, code-signing, codesign, code-signing-certificate

I have Windows application that can run on OS X under Wine. For convenience I want to pack the application as OS X app (ZIP archive of `xxx.app` folder based on WineBottler).

Note that the main executable of the app (as defined by `CFBundleExecutable` tag of `Info.plist`) is a shell script, not a binary.

I want to sign the application to pass through OS X Gatekeeper. As my complete build process runs on Windows (and as I actually do not have Mac at all) I need to sign it on Windows.

I already found that signing the app creates `_CodeSignature` folder with four files:

```
CodeDirectory
CodeRequirements
CodeResources
CodeSignature
```

I have not found any specification describing contents of these files.

Experimentally, I've found that `CodeResources` is an XML file with SHA-1 hashes of all files in the app. I can generate that.

The contents of `CodeRequirements` binary file seems to be fixed. It does not seem to change  with contents of the app. Confirmation is appreciated. What is this file good for?

As for the binary files `CodeDirectory` and `CodeSignature` I have no clue.

Both files change with app contents. It seems that any app file change (including plain text license file) affects them.

The `CodeSignature` obviously contains the signature. I can see plain-text information about code signing certificate in the file. Is there any tool that can generate the file? As it is a signature, it should be pretty standard. Though there can be some additional binary metadata that can make generation more difficult. Does anyone know what does it specifically sign? I can imagine that it signs only `CodeResources` file as that describes all other files in the app. Or does it actually sign all the files in the app recursively?

Native OS X apps have `CodeResources` only. So there's actually no signature in `_CodeSignature`. I suppose it's because they have embedded signature in the main executable binary. Note that my [Windows] binary (though it's not directly referred to by `Info.plist` as mentioned above) is code-signed using Windows `signtool.exe`. Apparently OS X recognizes the signature even without the reference as `codesign -d -vvv xxx.app` output includes information about the certificate:

```
Executable=/Applications/WinSCP.app/Contents/MacOS/startwine
Identifier=WinSCP
Format=bundle with generic
CodeDirectory v=20100 size=135 flags=0x0(none) hashes=1+3 location=embedded
Hash type=sha1 size=20
CDHash=a1ef4f04b2c1b4b793788ce3ab9d7881528f3d95
Signature size=4867
Authority=Martin Prikryl
Authority=VeriSign Class 3 Code Signing 2010 CA
Authority=VeriSign Class 3 Public Primary Certification Authority - G5
Signed Time=23.4.2014 23:51:18
Info.plist entries=14
Sealed Resources version=2 rules=12 files=846
Internal requirements count=2 size=136
```

Confusing is that is does not mention binary name at all. Anyway, it does not make Gatekeeper happy. Note the the above test is run against app that already includes `CodeResources` file (that's probably what the `Sealed Resources version` refers too as `rules` and `files` counts match with the file contents).

Comment: Is the binary in Mach-O format?

Comment: No, it's Windows binary.

Comment: Wouldn't you be better of pursuing a cross-platform framework solution, such as Qt, and build separate Windows and Mac binaries?  While you might be able to get this to work, the UX would be pretty poor I would imagine.

Comment: Well, this is not really relevant to the question, but to answer you: I do not aim for cross platform solution. I focus on Windows. But as there are quite some users who use (or want to use) the application on OS X, I want to make their life easier. Packing the application as Wine app is about the effort I'm willing put to this. Reimplementing the app in Qt is a way beyond.

Comment: What does the app even do? Most wine apps will be very out of place and weird on OS X. Qt also. It's not about looks. It's about OS conventions and user expectations.

Comment: Did you read Apple's Code Signing Guide ( https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/security/conceptual/CodeSigningGuide/CodeSigningGuide.pdf )? It answers at least some of your questions.

Comment: @danielv Thanks for the link. I've actually seen it before, but read it more carefully again now. It confirmed my assumption that `CodeRequirements` is not part of the signature as such and that I should be looking mainly at `CodeDirectory` and `CodeSignature`. Unfortunately there's no description of their structure.

Comment: By the way, the codesign utility and the codesigning library source code is open and available: http://www.opensource.apple.com/source/security_systemkeychain/security_systemkeychain-55191/src/ - http://opensource.apple.com/source/libsecurity_codesigning/ . It has been tried before but I don't think it was ever compiled on non Mac platforms. But you might find useful information there if you wade through the source code.

Comment: I'm not sure it's even possible to sign an application that has a shell script as the primary executable. Code signing requires that the binary be a MachO executable.

Comment: @duskwuff That's not true. Just try it. `codesign` can sign virtually anything. If there's no MachO executable, it stores the signature into `_CodeSignature` folder instead of into the executable.

Comment: @danielv Thanks for the links. Looking at it. Will come back with my findings.

Comment: @MartinPrikryl: Right, but I don't think a `_CodeSignature` is sufficient for the primary executable, since it only contains hashes, not a signature (i.e, from a trusted certificate).

Comment: Thanks to source code pointed to by @danielv I've found that `CodeDirectory` contains hashes of all files in the bundle and `CodeSignature` is signature [using specified trusted certificate] of the `CodeDirectory`. So the signature actually signs every single file of the bundle.

Comment: Have you considered a virtual machine running Mac OS?

Comment: Check out [isign](https://github.com/appknox/isign), it is a python implementation of codesign

Answer (score 9, accepted):

We have tried to reverse-engineer the code signing using source code of `libsecurity_codesigning` library. Although it seems feasible, it's still too much effort, so we consider giving up. We would like to at least share what we have found so far, so others may build upon.

We have found that when `codesign` does not find MachO binary, it falls back to "architecture agnostic" signing implemented in `SecCodeSigner::Signer::signArchitectureAgnostic`.

Key steps there:

- `CodeDirectory` file generation. The directory includes few SHA-1 hashes of various pieces of the bundle in addition to file header (including directory version)
- `CodeSignature` file generation. The signature signs `CodeDirectory` file using Cryptographic Message Syntax (CMS) format. The signature can be verified on any platform using OpenSSL:

  ```
  openssl cms -verify -in CodeSignature -inform DER
      -content CodeDirectory -noverify -out CodeDirectory.verified
  ```

  Note that `-noverify` is needed to skip certificate validation as OpenSSL does not seem to support "code signing" purpose of certificates.

  OpenSSL should be able to create CMS signature using following command:

  ```
  openssl cms -sign -in CodeDirectory -out CodeSignature 
      -signer certificate.pem -outform DER
  ```

  But such signature is not accepted by OS X.

We didn't get any further.

Comment: Hi, just wondering if you made some more progress in this area... I'm trying to build signature verifier to macho file on linux server using openssl.. verify the CMS signature chain is one thing, But I'm struggling to find out how to validate the file contents hash (what parts of the macho file goes to what hashes in `CodeDirectory`. perhaps do you know how to calculate them ? thanks !

Answer (score 3):

Not strictly signing on Windows, but have you considered Remote Desktop into a friends Mac or renting a Mac in the Cloud? http://www.macincloud.com seems to have fairly reasonable plans.

Could save a lot of the trouble. All you really need access to is the codesign tool and the Terminal.

Edit: You will still need an Apple Developer account to sign the application - Gatekeeper only allows signatures from Apple-issued developer ID certificates.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I was considering this approach too. Note that you do not need Apple-issued certificate. I was able to sign application using `codesign` even with VeriSign certificate I have for signing Windows 8 Store applications. Gatekeeper was happy too.

Comment: Has anyone successfully used MacinCloud for this purpose? I've just noticed that they have a 1$/hour prepaid plan which seems to be perfect for infrequent, short-time usages.